# dynamically updating select boxes with php mysql jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to populate an initial customer select box with results from PDO MySql via PHP. Then I would like the second contact select box to update with additional information related to what was chosen in the first box. I can't get the second script to work. I think the problem is in my ajax script because the PHP scripts work fine when ran on there own.

The Primary Script

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#contact").change(function(){
                 var cid = $("#cid").val();
                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"contact.php",
                    data:"cid="+cid,
                    success: function(data) {
                      $("#contact").html(data);
                    }
                 });
            });
       });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    Campaign :
    <select name="customer" id="customer">
      <option>-Select a Customer-</option>
    <?php 
    include ("function.php");
  include("connect.php");
    $id = $_SESSION['profile']['id']; 
   foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE pid = '$id'") as $row) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
        ?>
    </select>



    <select name="contact" id="contact">
        <option>-Select a Contact-</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Contact script

```
    include("connect.php");
$cid = $_POST["cid"];
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE cid = '$cid'") as $row) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your second function should start on `#customer` change

Answer (score 0):

I see you used the contact select in ajax not customer as you described. However the code you wrote, you used the contact selector with change event, But the contact select box contain only one value, How can it change ??

```
<select name="contact" id="contact">
    <option>-Select a Contact-</option>
</select>
```

The previous select should has more than option to can change. Or I think you mean the #customer instead contact as following:-

```
 $("#customer").change(function(){
                 //  your code;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just [encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) a JSON response with the ids and names?

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE cid = '$cid'") as $row) {
    $arr[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "name" => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Then in your ajax response, you could do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#customer").change(function () {
        var cid = $("#customer").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: {cid: cid},
            success: function (data) {
                var options = [];
                $.each(data, function () {
                    options.push('<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>');
                });
                $("#contact").html(options.join(""));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed to the scrip you suggested and now I don't even get the <option>-Select a Contact-</option> all I see is a down arrow

Comment: Disregard what I just said I get nothing in the contact drop-down just the hard coded stuff.

Comment: I just noticed something else wrong with your code. I will update answer

Comment: Open your browser network tab in developer tools and tell me what the json response looks like when you change one of the dropdowns

Comment: contact.php
/notaryaccounting
POST
200
OK
text/html
jquery-1.11.0.js:9666
Script
379 B
4 B
19 ms
19 ms

Comment: click the **response** tab after clicking on the contact.php call

Comment: I added  fixed number in the contact.php file and ran the script. It did not give me a contact drop down but it did give me the proper data in the network:preview

Comment: Can you post the object? ex: `{id: 1, name: 'foo'}`

Comment: I get null looks like it is not passing the cid [{"id":"1","name":"Tom"},{"id":"2","name":"Fred"},{"id":"3","name":"Same"}]

Comment: change `$cid` to `$_POST['cid']`

Comment: This is what the object looks like when I hard code the cid in.

Comment: $cid is set to $_POST['cid']

Comment: `cid` should be this: `var cid = $("#customer").val();`

Comment: Ok changed it and not it is sending if to network Response   [{"id":"1","name":"Tom"},{"id":"2","name":"Fred"},{"id":"3","name":"Same"}] It is not adding anything to the drop down