# How to use dynamic drop down in android using ajax?

Tags: android, ajax

I have to make an android app which create task, for this I have to select more then one member. I am trying to use a dynamic drop down to select more then one member name from the list which is coming from server database ..... for this I have to use ajax call but I don't understand how should I use this...... If anyone have idea, please help me?

Comment: are you using HTML5 Technology forApp development ?

Comment: am using php ... for android app

Comment: There isn't ajax for a native app, they are just http requests. A traditional dynamic drop-down list (for web pages) might be problematic because of the pop up keyboard and limited screen size of a mobile phone

Comment: @Farah: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083305/dynamically-updating-select-boxes-with-php-mysql-jquery-ajax check this.. you will get lot of examples for your rquirement!

Comment: Actually I want this functionality in my android app ...... waht should I do to fullfil this functionality?

Comment: are you using PHP in your android code?

Comment: Normally you have a Server side and you call an API to server and server returns the value as JSON or XML. then you can append the values to your select box using jQuery